# How can I set breakpoints by the sourcefile line number in Delve?

Tags: debugging, go, delve

The title pretty much says it all.

The only way I know how to set one is either during the runtime of the program or just before with `breakpoint main.main`

Is there a way I can do this by line number like `breakpoint ./otherfile.go:200`?

Comment: Not really an answer, but you can try to use a UI, visual studio code's [Go](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go) plugin has excellent support for delve.

Comment: I'm running on linux so... so visual studio for me :(

Comment: I think `break ./otherfile.go:200` should work. If not this is probably a bug. See https://github.com/derekparker/delve/wiki/Location-specifiers

Comment: vscode runs great on Linux, I'm using it on Arch Linux right now. https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Really?!? I haven't looked at visual studio years. When did they add Linux support?

Comment: It's not Visual Studio, it's Visual Studio Code - think Atom... or Sublime text editor - https://code.visualstudio.com/

Answer (score 42):

In your Source code type

```
  runtime.Breakpoint()
```

type in the CLI

> dlv test

and then

> continue

The program will stop in the line of code where you set the breakpoint.

Comment: I was just about to open up a question asking for something that's similar to `debugger` in node. I'm glad this exists in go too.

Answer (score 11):

The following is valid in delve:

```
(dlv) break <breakpoint_name> <filename_pattern>:<line_number>
```

If you have ambiguous filenames, say `main.go` spread all over your sources and possibly vendor directory, just make you make it look "unique" to delve (filename_pattern is not your exact file location). For example:

```
(dlv) break myLoopingStuff project_name/loops.go:30
(dlv) condition myLoopingStuff thing == someOther.thing
```